# Vim Colorscheme

Tags: vim, text-editors

What do I change in vimrc to make the while and if/else/elseif in this screenshot a different color?

[image]

EDIT-----------------------

This is a custom colorscheme and I am wondering what I change in the vim colorscheme file to change the colors of what I listed...sorry if that was unclear,

Comment: This isn't an answer, but try: colorscheme koehler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color scheme, just add a `colorscheme` directive in your vimrc, e.g.

```
colorscheme ron
```

To modify an existing colorscheme, [Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands or put them in your vimrc:

```
syn keyword myCIfElse if else
hi myCIfElse guifg=#CCCCCC guibg=NONE gui=NONE ctermfg=darkgray ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `synIDattr()`, `synID()` and `synIDtrans()` functions as shown at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor to show which highlight group you need to change in order to change the color of any syntax element. Then you just edit your colorscheme to add or modify a `:hi` command for that group.